# Using Images instead of styles

Tags: android, achartengine

In my application i implemented the line graph. But i want to use the images instead of some styles like points,circles etc. I tried but i am not getting it. please can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot. The only solution would be to checkout the AChartEngine code and write this custom feature yourself.